# Calculating SQL query on a string field

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a database called Students. DB has a "status" string field with 3 possible values; missing, absent, present. I have Calculated SQL DB called "stats". In the "stats" I have a "name" and "number" fields.

I'm stuck adding scripting that can load a chart with a total number of missing, present, and absent students.

Comment: Please provide your current code

Comment: I have a new datasource defined with the following query SELECT COUNT(Missing) FROM Students;